# How do I change the contents of a preference dialog when it is tapped?

Tags: android

I have implemented the onPreferenceClick(Preference) callback interface

```
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {

 if (arg0 instanceof ListPreference){
  addListPreferenceEntriesFromStore((ListPreference) arg0, getSharedPreferences("cfn_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE));
 }

 else if (arg0 instanceof EditTextPreference){
  ((EditTextPreference)arg0).setTitle("Hallabalooo");
  ((EditTextPreference)arg0).setDialogTitle("Tjillevipp");
 }

 return true;
}
```

When I tap the EditTextPreference for the first time the title, in the PreferenceScreen, is changed as expected but the dialog title isn't. The second time I tap the EditTextPreference the dialog title is also updated.

I experience the same behaviour with the ListPreference. The addListPreferenceEntriesFromStore() method updates the contents of the ListPreference, but the change isn't visible the first time the ListPreference is displayed.

It seems like changes made to the dialog part of a preference during the context of the onPreferenceClick() callback doesn't show.

What is it I do wrong here? Or is there a workaround?

Thankful for any help

/Mathias

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me.  The trick is to update the Preference object in onPreferenceChange.

First, make sure you have a reference to your Preference object in your class.

private EditTextPreference myPreference;

Then add a listener for onPreferenceChange.  Before you leave the method, update the object with the new value.  I think the problem is that the new value isn't getting set in the dialog here.

public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object objValue) {

```
    if (preference == myPreference) {

        // other stuff you need to do <here>

        myPreference.setText((String)objValue);

        return false; // don't update pref value
    }
    return true;
}
```